# How to process events in order for a specific key

Tags: java, threadpool

I didn't find a good question title for my problem.

I have a listener that receives events, each event has an object id. Because some actions take some time to process, I switch to a synchronous processing (where I treat each event one at a time, locking the listener) to a fixed thread pool executor (with 10 threads).

The problem is that for a specific object id, I still want to process events in the same order the events are emitted.

The problem is that the object id is random, I can't pre-declare a thread for each object id.

If I want to simplify it: let's say I have an array of threads, each event with id 0 would be treated via thread at index 0, and for each event with 1 they would be treated via thread at index 1.

It works well if id is within a range, like 0 to 10, but this is not my case, they can have any int value.

Comment: Can you share examples to help us understand better? You mean you want to process the events in sequential manner or process them parallely but events with same order should be processed in sequential manner.

Comment: I still want to process them parallely but only when object id is different, I want 2 events with the same id to be processed sequentialy

Comment: Will you wait for more events to come for an object id or you will process what ever events are available at the time of processing also what you want to do when the events are received during the processing of object id.

Comment: Indeed I have forgotten to give this information, inside events, there are "start" and "end" events, so a start event could create something, and the end event will clear anything that could have been setup to process these events

Comment: In that case you need to have one queue per thread to push in all the events with same id to same queue. Like based on hashing and mod function. And have threads to pop data from those queues and process them. As long as the queue is not empty, your threads should be continuously running and processing. And meanwhile you have a logic to push events to these queues based on object id. This is more like partitioning the stream of data based on a primary key and process them.

Comment: So a thread / pool could have to manage differents id at the same time ?

Comment: Need not be a thread pool. You explicitly define a map and init it with int and the single thread. Once you receive any event take the object ID and calculate the hashcode and then mod it by the total number of threads you have. This will ensure that you same object will always go to same thread.

Comment: thanks, if you want to post this as a reply, i will gladly vote for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To process the events of an object ID you need to make sure that it is coming to same thread for processing. To do that what you can do is you can calculate the hash of the object ID and then mod it by the number of threads you have which will make sure the same object ID is processed by same thread or by same threadpool.

```
int objectIdHash = objectId.hashCode();
    
return (objectIdHash % totalThreads);
```

Now to store the threads or threadpool for processing you can use the concurrent HashMap.

```
// Define the thread pool
private Map<Integer, ExecutorService> threadPool = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, ExecutorService>();

// Get the thread id using the above
int threadId = getJobThreadPoolId(objectId, totalThreads);

// Get the thread from the threadpool and submit
threadpool.get(threadId).submit(event);
```